# Azure SQL Data IO 100% for extended periods for no apparent reason

Tags: performance, azure, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure website running about 100K requests/hour and it connects to Azure SQL S2 database with about 8GB throughput/day.  I've spent a lot of time optimizing the database indexes, queries, etc.  Normally the Data IO, CPU and Log IO percentages are well behaved in the 20% range.

A recent portion of the data throughput is retained for supporting our customers.  I have a nightly maintenance procedure that removes obsolete data to manage database size.  This mostly works well with the exception of removing image blobs in a varbinary(max) field.

The nightly procedure has a loop that sets 10 records varbinary(max) field to null at a time, waits a couple seconds, then sets the next 10.  Nightly total for this loop is about 2000.

This loop will run for about 45 - 60 minutes and then stop running with no return to my remote Sql Agent job and no error reported.  A second and sometimes third running of the procedure is necessary to finish setting the desired blobs to null.

In an attempt to alleviate the load on the nightly procedure, I started running a job once every 30 seconds throughout the day - it sets one blob to null each time.

Normally this trickle job is fine and runs in 1 - 6 seconds.  However, once or twice a day something goes wrong and I can find no explanation for it.  The Data I/O percentage peaks at 100% and stays there for 30 - 60 minutes or longer.  This causes the database responsiveness to suffer and the website performance goes with it.  The trickle job also reports running for this extended period of time.  If I stop the Sql Agent job, it can take a few minutes to stop but the Data I/O continues at 100% for the 30 - 60 minute period.

The web service requests and database demands are relatively steady throughout the business day - no volatile demands that would explain this.  No database deadlocks or other errors are reported.  It's as if the database hits some kind of backlog limit where its ability to keep up suddenly drops and then it can't catch up until something that is jammed finally clears.  Then the performance will suddenly return to normal.

Do you have any ideas what might be causing this intermittent and unpredictable issue?  Any ideas what I could look at when one of these events is happening to determine why the Data I/O is 100% for an extended period of time?  Thank you.

Comment: If you are in SQL DB V12, you may want to try run sp_whoisactive (http://sqlblog.com/files/folders/release/tags/who+is+active/default.aspx)  in a loop to collect the required information. The other option is to snapshot the sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats , active transactions, and sys.dm_Exec_requests at regular intervals particularly when the IO is peaking to see who is causing this.

Comment: Update: @@version returns 11.0.9230.282 although the portal server version is listed as V2.  I will be upgrading to V12 some weekend.

Comment: I've used things like sys.dm_exec_query_stats and noticed that when the issue is happening all the Avg CPU Times are dramatically increased over normal times.  This indicates many statistics may represent a symptom of server issues rather than the root causes.  Perhaps something like sys.dm_Exec_requests would be more informative.

Comment: Conclusion: The historical image blobs were used rarely, the image blob metadata in the other fields is more relevant.  I've sidestepped the issue by no longer retaining the blobs for historical reference.  Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on SQL DB V12, you may also consider using the [*Query Store* feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn817826.aspx) to root cause this performance problem. It's now in **public preview**.

In order to turn on Query Store just run the following statement:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE your_db SET QUERY_STORE = ON;
```